# how to set space between buttons and make text in one line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I use this code to draw the following line

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal" 



    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Chemo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chemo" 
        android:background="@drawable/firstbuttoncolorstyle"
        android:textColor="@drawable/firstbuttontextstyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inpatient"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="inpatient" 
        android:background="@drawable/firstbuttoncolorstyle"
         android:textColor="@drawable/firstbuttontextstyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Mgmt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mgmt" 
    android:background="@drawable/firstbuttoncolorstyle"
     android:textColor="@drawable/firstbuttontextstyle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="22dp" 
    />
      </LinearLayout>       
     <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PFinder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Patient" 
        android:background="@drawable/secondbuttoncolorstyle"
        android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Afinder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Appointement" 
        android:background="@drawable/secondbuttoncolorstyle"
        android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Calender"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calender" 
        android:background="@drawable/secondbuttoncolorstyle"
        android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        />

    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    >
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/Profile"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Profile" 
         android:background="@drawable/thirdbuttoncolorstyle"
         android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/Clear"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear" 

        android:background="@drawable/thirdbuttoncolorstyle"
        android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Logout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout" 
        android:background="@drawable/thirdbuttoncolorstyle"
        android:textColor="@drawable/secondbuttontextstyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22dp" 


        />



    </LinearLayout>



              <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    >
            <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/maillme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mail" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"
    />


                <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/callme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/call" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

    </LinearLayout>



   </LinearLayout>
```

but the following is the output

how to set space between the buttons and make for example the calender word in one line

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your example, you should reduce the textSize to 20... So `calendar` & `impatient` will fit in appropriately.

just a tip : use `sp` for textsize and `dp` for height and width of controls.

For margin you have : `android:layout_marginRight` and `android:layout_marginLeft`

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

for spacing you can use `android:layout_marginRight`, `android:layout_marginLeft` etc. properties and you should define `android:layout_width="WRAP_CONTENT"` to prevent behaviour like your calendar button nad next buttons have got.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_marginLeft = "5dp"` on every button after first `Button`, I think you can use `android:singleLine = "true"` to keep text in one line.

Also set the height to all buttons eual and use `android:layout_height = "wrap_content"` on your  main layout.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use Styles to reduce the length of code by reusing attributes like: `gravity, layout_height, textColor, ...`

As for the line breaks in some buttons. If you only deal with tablets you could use `layout_width="wrap_content"` to avoid the line breaks and have equal height for each button.

To have a little space between each button use the already mentioned `layout_marginLeft`